# Can I use an HDRI to illuminate the scene and another one for the background?

Tags: light

I want to illuminate my scene with an HDRI, and to use another one as a background image.

Answer (score 3):

In the world shader, use the light path node to differentiate between the two.

[image]

Result with a white cube :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this through compositor.

1. Enable World transparency in *Render > Film > Transparent*
2. In *Compositor*, connect your new background image, and let *alpha channel* drive the visibility.
   Don't forget to check  **✓** *Use Nodes*

*Enable World transparency*

[image]

*The reflection comes from HDRi, the background comes from external image.*

[image]

Comment: Ehm. The original question didn't mention using another HDRI as a background, but a simple image :).