# How can I add two world backgrounds?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, world

I made a space themed world background for my blender eevee scene. The only problem is that space is dark so the rest of my scene isn't lit up well. The way my scene is set up, it seems like the best course of action is to change my space background, but I would like to keep it. Is there any way I can have the space world background as well as another world background to give the scene light without compromising the space background?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359 Same concept, but replace emission with a world shader or better yet, mix at texture level

Comment: Use one HDR to light the scene and one to render as background. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81007/how-can-i-render-an-object-with-an-hdr-background

Comment: [how to use multiple HDRs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris)

Comment: [Can I use an HDRI to illuminate the scene and another one for the background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165399/can-i-use-an-hdri-to-illuminate-the-scene-and-another-one-for-the-background?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [How to set two different HDRI, one for environment lighting, and another for background, in 2.8 using Eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134183/how-to-set-two-different-hdri-one-for-environment-lighting-and-another-for-bac?noredirect=1&lq=1)